# convert array to XML so that its possible to make a post request with guzzle with the XML data

Tags: xml, laravel

Do you know how to convert this array ($array) into XML so that its possible to make a post request with guzzle with the XML data in the body?

```
$array= 'invoice' => [
    'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'due_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'client' => ['name' => 'John', 'code' => ''],
    'items' => [
        'item' => [
            'name' => 'reg1',
            'description' => 'reg1 on evt',
            'unit_price' => '10',
            'quantity' => '1.0'
        ],
        'item' => [
            'name' => 'reg1',
            'description' => 'reg1 on evt',
            'unit_price' => '10',
            'quantity' => '1.0'
        ]
    ]
]
```

To make the post request the xml needs to have the format:

```
<invoice>
 <date></date>
 <due_date></due_date>
 <client>
  <name></name>
  <code></code>
 </client>
 <items type="array">
  <item>
   <name></name>
   <description></description>
   <unit_price></unit_price>
   <quantity></quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
   <name></name>
   <description></description>
   <unit_price></unit_price>
   <quantity></quantity>
  </item>
 </items>
</invoice>
```

So that is possible to make the post request with the xml data like:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://testname.app.invoicexpress.com/invoices.xml', [
    'query' => ['api_key' => '...'],
    'body' => $bodyXML
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy with the below package, Just install the package via composer :

https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml

The implementation will be :

```
$array= 'invoice' => [
    'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'due_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'client' => ['name' => 'John', 'code' => ''],
    'items' => [
        'item' => [
            'name' => 'reg1',
            'description' => 'reg1 on evt',
            'unit_price' => '10',
            'quantity' => '1.0'
        ],
        'item' => [
            'name' => 'reg1',
            'description' => 'reg1 on evt',
            'unit_price' => '10',
            'quantity' => '1.0'
        ]
    ]
]
```

And then :

```
$result = ArrayToXml::convert($array);
```

Don't forget to include `use Spatie\ArrayToXml\ArrayToXml;` at the top of the class/Controller.

Comment: Thanks, its appearing this error "Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request." Do you know why?

Comment: The dd($result) shows "<?xml version="1.0"?>\n
<root>
    <invoice>
        <date>2018-06-17 18:58:51</date>
        <due_date>2018-06-17 18:58:51</due_date>
        <client>
                <name>John</name>
                <code></code>
        </client>
        <items>
            <item>
                <name>reg1</name>
                <description>reg1 on evt</description>
                <unit_price>10</unit_price>
                <quantity>1.0</quantity>
            </item>
        </items>
    </invoice>
</root>".

Comment: Its not the issue of the above package or code, Its your request that is causing the problem. You should accept the answer and post another question for the problem with a bit code.

Comment: Yes, dd() will show the exact same thing which you want. So there is no issue in the conversation array to xml.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released a package that helps convert data to valid xml. It is based on Spatie's array to xml package.

You can find it here: https://github.com/mtownsend5512/collection-xml

It has some handy global helpers, such as `array_to_xml()` and you can convert a collection by doing `$collection->toXml()`.